# Numbering equations with (B.1), (B.2)

Tags: equations, numbering

How to create numbering in this way: (A), (B), (B.1), (B.2) etc. with 
\enumerate ?

Thanks for any advice.

(edited in from comment:)

```
\begin{subequations}
 \renewcommand{\theequation}{\theparentequation.\Alph{equation}}
 \begin{align}
  y & = d \\ y & = cx+d \\
  y & = bx^{2}+cx+d \\ y & = ax^{3}+bx^{2}+cx+d
 \end{align}
\end{subequations}
```

Comment: More details on the context would be helpful. Do you want to redefine numbering of *all* equations in a document, or *a certain type* of equations?

Comment: I want to redefine a certain type of equations.

Comment: And they need their own counter (for the numeric part)?

Comment: Yes, they need their own counter.

Comment: The answers to [how-to-create-new-counter-of-equation](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/84254/how-to-create-new-counter-of-equation) seem to solve your problem.

Comment: A warm welcome to TeX.SE!  Although it seems that @Bernard has pointed in the right direction you might want to post a _MWE_ http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3343/what-makes-a-good-mwe

Comment: I've tried code that was in  [how-to-create-new-counter-of-equation](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/84254/how-to-create-new-counter-of-equation)  , but did't work well

Comment: Post what you tried, that we can play with…

Comment: \begin{subequations}
\renewcommand{\theequation}{\theparentequation.\Alph{equation}}
\begin{align}
y & = d \\
y & = cx+d \\
y & = bx^{2}+cx+d \\
y & = ax^{3}+bx^{2}+cx+d
\end{align}
\end{subequations}

Comment: i edited in your example from the comment, but we really need more.  please make this compilable, with `\documentclass`, `amsmath` package if needed, and `\begin ... \end{document}`.  you are always able to edit your own question.

Comment: I don't see an `enumerate` in there!