# How to right-align part of an equation in display math mode

Tags: math-mode, align

This is over a single line. I honestly thought it would be very simple but so far I have tried:

- `\hfill`
- `\hspace*{\fill}`
- `\null\hfill`
- `\hspace*{0pt}\hfill`
- `\mbox{}\hfill`

In the following line:

```
$$g(x) = \underset{c \in \mathcal{Y}}{\operatorname{arg max}} \mathcal{P}(f(x + \epsilon)=c), \hfill \epsilon \sim \mathcal{N}(0, \sigma^2I)$$
```

All of them result in:

[image]

If I just use inline math-mode with a new line, it results in the main equation being left-aligned. I want the main equation to be centrally aligned, with the noise right-aligned.

Comment: `flalign` does something like this.

Comment: What if you have a right-aligned equation tag?

Comment: @Someone `flalign` only works over multiple lines I believe? At least in this case using an ampersand doesn't move the noise to the right.

Comment: You seem to want something like `\begin{equation} g(x)...c), \tag{\epsilon \sim ...} \end{equation}`.  I'm pretty sure this is a duplicate.

Comment: @barbarabeeton ah yes, that works, thank you! I couldn't find any the same question anywhere.

Comment: @Somniare -- Here's one:  https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/420314  I used the search terms "tag flush right".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]

I'd use the last realization, as there is no reason for shoving the side condition to the right margin.

In any case, `$$` should ***never*** be used in a LaTeX `document` environment. Also note `\operatorname*` instead of `\underset`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

% these two packages just for the example
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{showframe}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1][1-4]
\[
\hspace{1000pt minus 1fill}
g(x) = \operatorname*{arg\,max}_{c \in \mathcal{Y}}\mathcal{P}(f(x + \epsilon)=c), 
\hspace{1000pt minus 1fill}
\epsilon \sim \mathcal{N}(0, \sigma^2I)
\]
\lipsum[2][1-4]
\[
\hspace{1000pt minus 1fill}
g(x) = \operatorname*{arg\,max}_{c \in \mathcal{Y}}\mathcal{P}(f(x + \epsilon)=c), 
\hspace{1000pt minus 1fill}
\makebox[0pt][r]{$\displaystyle \epsilon \sim \mathcal{N}(0, \sigma^2I)$}
\]
\lipsum[3][1-4]
\[
g(x) = \operatorname*{arg\,max}_{c \in \mathcal{Y}}\mathcal{P}(f(x + \epsilon)=c), 
\qquad \epsilon \sim \mathcal{N}(0, \sigma^2I)
\]
\lipsum[4][1-4]

\end{document}
```